# how to Filter webgrid in mvc4 based on textbox input and dropdownList input

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am still in learning curve of mvc4 . I know how to bind a webgrid in mvc4 . But my doubt is can anyone share me the idea how to bind webgrid based on filter conditions from textbox input and  dropdownList input. For eg : If textbox has a date "11/15/2013" and dropdownList has the doctor name "Charles" then i need to show in gridview the list of patients who has appointment with doctor " charles " on "11/15/2013" .

code

```
 <div id="gridContent">
 @grid.GetHtml(
 fillEmptyRows: true,
 tableStyle: "webGrid",
 alternatingRowStyle: "alternate-row",
 headerStyle: "grid-header",
    footerStyle: "grid-footer",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
     firstText: "<< First",
    previousText: "< Prev",
     nextText: "Next >",
    lastText: "Last >>",
    columns: new[] {        
    grid.Column("PatientID"),
    grid.Column("PatientName"),
    grid.Column("Age"),
    grid.Column("DOB"),
    grid.Column("Sex"),
    grid.Column("Phone"),
    grid.Column("Mobile"),
    grid.Column("City"),
    grid.Column("PinCode"),

   // grid.Column("Dr_Remarks",header:"Remarks",style:"left"),


    //grid.Column("Dr_Add1", 
    //            header: "Bed Count",style:"right"
    //),

    grid.Column("", 
                header: "Actions",
                format: @<text> 
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditPatient", new { id = item.PatientID }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "link" })
    |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "PatientList", new { id = item.PatientID },
             htmlAttributes: new { @class = "link", onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this record?');" })
     </text>
    )
  })
  </div>


    **controller**

        public ActionResult PatientList(int page = 1, string sort = "Dr_Id", string sortDir = "ASC", int id = 0)
    {
        if (id != 0)
        {
            bool isDelete = false;
            isDelete = rdm_Patient.DeletePatient(id);


            return View(GetPatient(page, sort, sortDir));
        }
        else
        {
            return View(GetPatient(page, sort, sortDir));
        }
    } 

     private PatientPageViewModel GetPatient(int page = 1, string sort = "Dr_Id", string sortDir = "ASC")
    {
        const int patientPerPage = 5;
        var numPatient = rdm_Patient.CountPatient();
        sortDir = sortDir.Equals("desc", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? sortDir : "asc";
        var validColumns = new[] { "PatientID", "PatientName" };
        if (!validColumns.Any(c => c.Equals(sort, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
            sort = "PatientID";
        var doctors = rdm_Patient.getpatientpage(page, patientPerPage, "it." + sort + " " + sortDir);
        var data = new PatientPageViewModel()
        {

            numberOfPatient = numPatient,
            patientPerPage = patientPerPage,
            Patient = doctors,
        };
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Refer This Link Which Can Help You.
http://www.authorcode.com/filtering-records-in-webgrid-using-dropdownlist-in-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

As I understand of your question you need filtering in your WebGrid that doesn’t include any kind of tool to perform it. So, you have to do it manually.

You should take into account the following points:

- Firstly, include a form in the View where the query criteria is collected in order to send it to the controller.
- Secondly, prepare the Controller so it can receive this criteria and make it reach the Model.
- Thirdly, in the Model, simply apply this criteria when counting the total amount of rows, and when obtaining the data to be displayed in the grid page.

[Jose M. Aguilar](http://www.campusmvp.net/blog/asp-net-mvc-webgrid-with-filtering-paging-and-sorting) in his post describes all steps which can help you to design your view and controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
Index.cshtml:
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Employee
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("lstdepartment", Model.Department_List)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="EmployeeViewGrid">
               @Html.Partial("EmployeeView",Model.Employee_Grid)
            </div>  
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#lstdepartment').change(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = '@Url.Action("Filter")';
        $.get(url, { department: $(this).val() }, function (result) {
            debugger;
            $('#EmployeeViewGrid').html(result);
        });
    });
</script>

Partial view:

@model List< MvcApplication1.Models.Employee>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EmployeeView";
}

<h2>EmployeeView</h2>
<div id="gridposition" style="overflow: scroll; height: 300px; overflow-x: hidden;">
    @{
        var grid1 = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");

        @grid1.GetHtml(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",
            rowStyle: "description",
            htmlAttributes: new { id = "positionGrid" },
            fillEmptyRows: false,

            columns: grid1.Columns(

             grid1.Column("EmployeeId", header: "EmployeeId"),
             grid1.Column("EmpName", header: "EmpName"),
             grid1.Column("Age", header: "Age"),
             grid1.Column("Department", header: "Department"),
             grid1.Column("Salary", header: "Salary")))
    }
</div>

Controller:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication1.Models;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private EmployeeDatabaseEntities1 db = new EmployeeDatabaseEntities1();

        //
        // GET: /Employee/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Employee _model = new Employee();
            //_model.Employee_Grid = db.tbl_Employee.ToList();
            var departmentlist = db.tbl_department.ToList();

            _model.Department_List = (from d in departmentlist
                                      select new SelectListItem
                    {

                        Value = d.department_id.ToString(),
                        Text = d.department_name
                    }).ToList();

            var qq = (from e in db.tbl_Employee
                      join d in db.tbl_department on e.Department_id equals d.department_id
                      select new Employee
                      {
                          Department_id=e.Department_id,
                          EmployeeId=e.EmployeeId,
                          EmpName=e.EmpName,
                          Age=e.Age,
                          Department=d.department_name
                      }).ToList();
            _model.Employee_Grid = qq;
            return View("Index", _model);
        }


        public ActionResult Filter(string department)
        {
            int? department_id = Convert.ToInt32(department);
       var qq = (from e in db.tbl_Employee
                      join d in db.tbl_department on e.Department_id equals d.department_id
                 where e.Department_id == department_id
                      select new Employee
                      {
                          Department_id = e.Department_id,
                          EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,enter code here
                          EmpName = e.EmpName,
                          Age = e.Age,
                          Department = d.department_name
                      }).ToList();
               return PartialView("EmployeeView",qq);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Please mention that why have you posted all this code??